# MX record format without mail.domain.com

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, dns-zone

Let us say I have a domain `example.com` that points to IP `192.0.2.4`, hence in the DNS I would see:

```
example.com  A  192.0.2.4
www.example.com  CNAME  example.com
```

Now, most `MX` records appear to be set in this way into the DNS

```
example.com  MX 10 mail.example.com
mail.example.com  A  192.0.2.4
```

Can I just do this?

```
example.com  MX 10 example.com
```

**By leaving out the**: `mail.example.com  A 10 192.0.2.4`

P.S. I looked into [RFC "3.3.9. MX RDATA format"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) but it doesn't seem to say much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course you can create such an MX record. When all your services are running on a single ip-address and/or a single server and the host that will receive mail for `@example.com` IS `example.com`.

```
example.com.      IN  MX 0  example.com. 
example.com.      IN  A     203.0.113.1
```

There is no requirement to do this:

```
example.com.      IN  MX 0  mail.example.com. 
example.com.      IN  A     203.0.113.1
mail.example.com. IN  A     203.0.113.1
```

But in that scenario you can also simply omit creating MX records entirely. When no MX records are found for `@example.com` SMTP will deliver mail directly to the host  `example.com` .

See  [RFC 5321 §5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5)

> ... If an empty list of MXs is returned,
> the address is treated as if it was associated with an implicit MX
> RR, with a preference of 0, pointing to that host.

Comment: "you can also simply omit creating MX records entirely", I don't recommend this. One of the weights that spam filters use is a check for an MX record. If a sending domain has no MX record, it's considered more likely to be spam.

Comment: Maybe, but for receiving mail that is not an requirement